# Divisor gives rise to meromorphic function -- Griffiths and Harris

Tags: complex-analysis, algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

In $\textit{Griffiths and Harris, Principles of Algebraic Geometry}$ on page 131, they prove that a divisor gives rise to a meromorphic function.

> Given $D=\sum_i a_i V_i$, we can find an open cover $M=\bigcup_{\alpha} U_{\alpha}$ of $M$, such that in each $U_{\alpha}$, every $V_i$ appearing in $D$ has a local defining function $g_{i\alpha}\in \mathcal{O}(U_{\alpha})$. We can then set
>   $$
> f_{\alpha}=\prod_i g_{i\alpha}^{a_i} \in \mathfrak{M}^\ast(U_{\alpha}).
> $$

$\textbf{Questions:}$

$\textbf{1)}$ Why is $f_{\alpha}$ meromorphic on $U_{\alpha}$? That is, given $x\in U_{\alpha}$, why does $f_{\alpha}$ define an element in $\operatorname{Frac}(\mathcal{O}_{M,x})$? In other words, considering each $g_{i\alpha}$ as an element in $\mathcal{O}_{M,x}$ and cancelling common factors, why is the denominator of the resulting expression non-zero in $\mathcal{O}_{M,x}$ for every $x\in U_{\alpha}$?

$\textbf{2})$ Why is it a unit in $\mathfrak{M}(U_{\alpha})$, i.e. why is $f_{\alpha}\in \operatorname{Frac}(\mathcal{O}_{M,x})$ non-zero for all $x\in U_{\alpha}$ (after cancelling common factors)?

Help is highly appreciated.

Comment: @JohnMa right, I meant to say that $f_{\alpha}$ defines a non-zero element in $\operatorname{Frac}(\mathcal{O}_{M,x})$

Comment: For 2, fixes $\alpha$ and consider $y\in U_\alpha \setminus V_1\cup \cdots \cup V_k$. So $g_{i\alpha} (y) \neq 0$ for all $i$ and so $f_\alpha (y)\neq 0$. Thus $f_\alpha$ is a non-zero element.

Comment: @JohnMa so we may assume that $U_{\alpha}$ meets only finitely many $V_i$'s. say $V_1,\ldots,V_k$, then can't $U_{\alpha}$ be contained in $V_1\cup \ldots \cup V_k$?

Comment: First of all, the sum in the definition of $D$ is finite. Second, one needs to show (as you said) $U_\alpha$ is not contained in the union of $V_i's$. This is done in Chapter zero of the book (I need to check where exactly it is though)

Comment: Well, the $V_i$'s are codimension one closed sets so they can't contain any open set. Also note for 2 that being a unit doesn't mean $f_\alpha$ doesn't vanish anywhere, it means that it's not the 0 function.

Comment: @user347489 Could you please give a bit more explanation for why the union of the $V_i$'s cannot contain an open subset? For me a meromorphic function $f$ is a map $f\colon M\to \coprod_{x\in M} \operatorname{Frac}(\mathcal{O}_{M,x})$ being locally represented by the fraction of two holomorphic functions. So this will be invertible if $f(x)$ is non-zero in $\operatorname{Frac}(\mathcal{O}_{M,x})$ for all $x\in M$, or am I wrong?

Comment: The key observation is that an open set of a manifold has the same dimension as the manifold itself. On the other hand, by definition the $V_i$'s have dimension one less.

Comment: About the other remark, there is a difference between evaluation of $f$ at $x$, which I denote by $f(x)$, and the stalk of $f$ at $x$, which I denote by $f_x$. Indeed, what you want to see is that $f_x\neq 0$, however this doesn't mean $f(x)\neq 0,\infty$. Perhaps I was the only one confused by the notation above.

Comment: @user347489  But how does this argument show that $(f_{\alpha})_x$ is non-zero in $\operatorname{Frac}(\mathcal{O}_{M,x})$ for all $x\in U_{\alpha}$? We proved that there exists some $y$ for which $(f_{\alpha})_y\neq 0$.

Comment: @user347489 I guess, if we replace $U_{\alpha}$ by a connected component, then this will again be open since $M$ is locally connected. Now removing all the $g_{i\alpha}$'s with $a_i<0$, we obtain a holomorphic function and by the same argument this defines a non-zero germ at some point $y$ in the connected component and thus it defines a non-zero germ at every point in the connected component. Doing this for every connected component gives the desired result. But I still have no clue about 1.

Comment: I don't understand. For example on a complex torus there is no meromorphic function with one simple zero or pole. So what $g_{i \alpha}$ is supposed to be ? If $V_i$ is itself the divisor of a meromorphic function then the statement is obvious. @user347489

Comment: @reuns what comment of mine are you addressing?

Comment: @reuns I'm having a hard time seeing what's the problem (BTW I'm not the OP). WLOG we can assume our cover consists of charts of the manifold. In this case the $g_{i\alpha}$ would just be a polynomial equation $\mathbb{C}^n\to\mathbb{C}$ and $V_i\cap U_\alpha=g_{i\alpha}^{-1}(0)$. PS. We could move this to chat, but I don't know how.

Comment: @user347489 Ok, that's what I thought. Then for each $\alpha$, $\prod_i g_{i \alpha}^{a_i}$ is (trivially) meromorphic on $U_\alpha$ and its divisor of zeros/poles (on $U_\alpha$) is $\sum_i a_i V_i \cap U_\alpha$. But it doesn't define a globally meromorphic function. And if a globally meromorphic function $h$ with divisor $\sum_i a_i V_i$ exists, then $g_{i \alpha}^{a_i}$ is $h \circ \phi_\alpha$ for some $\phi_\alpha$

Comment: @reuns Could you please explain why there is no meromorphic function with one simple zero or pole on a complex torus?